# Use variable in gitlab workflow rules with regex

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have two rules. The first doesn't work, but the second does. I want to shorten a string using regular expressions, but when I run it I always get an error that the pipeline is filtered by workflow rules.

```
variables:
  DESTINATION:
    value: $CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE
  IMAGE_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG && $DESTINATION =~ /^$CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE-(prod|stage)$/'
      variables:
        IMAGE_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" && ($DESTINATION == "${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}-dev" || $DESTINATION == "${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}-qa"'
      variables:
        IMAGE_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
```

As a result, I want to launch the pipeline if the destination starts from $project_group-(prod or stage) and only from the tag.
Second rule not using regex and it works

Comment: You cannot use variables in regex patterns (between `/` pattern markers) for `rules:if:`. This is a [known limitation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/209904) at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a syntax error in the first rule where you are using regular expressions. The regular expression pattern should be enclosed in double quotes.

```
 variables:
  DESTINATION: $CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE
  IMAGE_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA

workflow:
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG && $DESTINATION =~ /^${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}-(prod|stage)$/'
      variables:
        IMAGE_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" && ($DESTINATION == "${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}-dev" || $DESTINATION == "${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}-qa")'
      variables:
        IMAGE_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA
```

I used double quotes to enclose the regular expression pattern and escaped the dollar sign in ${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}.

Comment: Thank you, @Star_Knight. But if I double quote the expression than pipeline will trigger by any pattern and not just ${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}-(prod|stage). So this is not helped...
`- if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG && "$DESTINATION =~ /^$${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}-(prod|stage)$/"'`

Comment: I see you're correct, and I hope this should work.  In GitLab CI, when using regular expressions, it's important to avoid unintended pattern matches.


`  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" && $CI_COMMIT_TAG && "$DESTINATION" =~ /^${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}-(prod|stage)$/'
      variables:
        IMAGE_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" && ($DESTINATION == "${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}-dev" || $DESTINATION == "${CI_PROJECT_ROOT_NAMESPACE}-qa")'
      variables:
        IMAGE_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA `